# Django: Помощь взятие объектов из бд

Tags: python, django

У меня есть проблема и я не знаю как ее решить. У меня есть модели, которые связаны ForeignKey

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class University(models.Model):
    university_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    decryption = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Institute(models.Model):
    institute_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    decryption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Faculty(models.Model):
    faculty_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    decryption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    decryption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    dean = models.ManyToManyField(Faculty)
```

И есть формочки

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile, Regkey, University, Faculty, Institute, Group as groupdb

class UserProfileStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    university = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select)
    group = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        data = super(UserProfileStudentForm, self).clean()
        group = data.get('group')
        university = data.get('university')
        if not groupdb.objects.select_related(Faculty__Institute).get(title=group):
            msg = 'Такой группы нет'
            self._errors['group'] = self.error_class([msg])
            del data['group']
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('middle_name',)


class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    second_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def clean(self):
        data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        email = data.get("email")
        if User.objects.filter(email = email):
            msg = 'Эта электронная почта занята'
            self._errors['email'] = self.error_class([msg])
            del data['email']
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

В формочке пользователь вводит University и Group. Мне надо что бы проверялось что в базе данных есть группа и она связанна с University. Сложность в том что University и Group связанны через другие модели. Заранее Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно доработать класс UserProfileStudentForm таким образом

```
class UserProfileStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
   university = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select)
   group = forms.CharField()

   ...
    def clean_group(self):
        group = self.cleaned_data['group']
        university = self.cleaned_data['university']
        if not Group.objects.filter(faculty__institute__university=university, id=group).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Такой группы нет в выбранном университете!")

        return group
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('middle_name',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то требуется провалидировать наличе ключа в смежной таблице. Это можно сделать при помощи `forms.ModelChoiceField()`

в общем случае выглядеть будет как-то так:

```
class UserProfileStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    university = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=University.objects.all())
```

Полный код приводить не буду. Ибо все остальные поля с первичным ключем делаются по образу и подобию

Comment: А по-другому никак нельзя? Я просто хочу что бы пользователь вводил только University и Group